# avoiding duplicate rows SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, datediff

Could you please suggest how can I avoid duplicate values for the below scenario.

I am using a `datediff` function for which my second parameter is getting more than one row and is causing an error.

```
SELECT COALESCE(DATEDIFF(DAY,'1987-01-19 00:00:00.000',( SELECT CASE WHEN  B.BILLDATE IS NULL THEN COALESCE(MIN(B.DUEDAY),0) ELSE COALESCE(MIN(B.BILLDATE),0) END BILL_DATE 
                                        FROM BILL B WHERE b.ORDERNR IN('2684667') GROUP BY BILLDATE)),0) res_col
```

For my second parameter I am getting two values. it may be because of `group by` clause in my sub-query.

For your information: one of the column  `B.DUEDAY` and `B.BILLDATE` can be null
or both of them can also be null.

Can you please suggest how can I get my desired result?

Comment: any reason why you want to group by `BILLDATE`? You also use `MIN(B.BILLDATE)` in your sub-query as well.

Comment: I don't need group by clause but i had to use for syntax correction.  I just want  if  billdate is null then min(dueday) else min(billdate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your criteria, which is not clear. It looks like you want to use BillDate and when it is null use due date, but what is not clear is when to do the null check (because your attempt is a mixture of both), e.g.

```
BillDate    DueDate
-------------------------
2015-04-01  NULL
NULL        2014-03-01
2015-04-30  2015-04-30
```

If you do the null check before the aggregate:

```
MIN(COALESCE(BillDate, DueDate)) --> 2015-03-01
```

You get a different answer to doing it after:

```
COALESCE(MIN(BillDate), MIN(DueDate)) --> 2015-04-01
```

Nonetheless, the answers are pretty similar and you don't need a subquery either:

```
SELECT  Method1 = COALESCE(DATEDIFF(DAY,
                                '1987-01-19 00:00:00.000',
                                COALESCE(MIN(BillDate), MIN(DueDate))), 0),
        Method2 = COALESCE(DATEDIFF(DAY,
                                '1987-01-19 00:00:00.000',
                                COALESCE(MIN(BillDate), MIN(DueDate))), 0)
FROM    BILL AS b
WHERE   b.ORDERNR IN('2684667');
```

Comment: Based on comments from OP, he is looking for `MIN(COALESCE(BillDate, DueDate))`. I also initially had an impression that he might need the minimum value from both columns.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `CASE` statement. You can directly use `COALESCE` like this `MIN(COALESCE(B.BILLDATE,B.DUEDAY),0)`. Your query would be something like this.

```
SELECT COALESCE(DATEDIFF(DAY,'1987-01-19 00:00:00.000',
    (
        SELECT MIN(COALESCE(B.BILLDATE,B.DUEDAY,0)) 
        FROM BILL B
        WHERE B.ORDERNR = '2684667'
    )
),0) res_col
```

Another simpler way to write this sql would be

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,'1987-01-19 00:00:00.000',MIN(COALESCE(B.BILLDATE,B.DUEDAY,0))) res_col
FROM BILL B
WHERE B.ORDERNR = '2684667'
```

Comment: Actually i want my second parameter will be ´if  billdate is null then min(dueday) else min(billdate).´

Comment: I had the `COEALESCE` mixed up, check updated answer